# jQuery set the width of List Items

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and the navigation menu elements are generated by users. Some users may only want 2 menu list items, some users may want 8 menu list items.

I want to be able to set the menu navigation element width based on the number of items there are in the menu. So for example, if there are 4 menu items then the li width would be set to 25%, if there are there are 2, then the li width would be set to 50%

Is there a way that jQuery could do this?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mainNav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 2</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a> </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get jQuery to set the width based on the number of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used the following code to set the width of the LIs based on the number there are:

```
$.fn.autowidth = function() {
return this.each(function() {        
    $('li', this).css({'width' : (100 / $('li', this).length) + '%'})
});
};
$('.mainNav').autowidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, this is one case where `flexbox` does an amazing job:

```
.mainNav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.mainNav li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

obviously with all the implications of browser support etc

Comment: Thanks. Is flexbox fully supported by all browsers  though?